# How to hide desktop to show only black screen

Tags: screen, desktop, fbi

How to hide desktop or to show black screen so I can display images and videos by fbi and omxplayer without seeing desktop when next image is loaded?

Comment: Like Milliways said, dont use the desktop. you can disable automatic desktop starting in `raspi-config`->`boot options`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to switch off the backlight if available for your display. On the command line you can do it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo "0" > /sys/class/backlight/soc\:backlight/brightness'
```

and on again:

```
rpi ~$ sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo "1" > /sys/class/backlight/soc\:backlight/brightness'
```

Answer (score 0):

`fbi` doesn't need a GUI so don't use one.

Comment: I need to run browser after fbi. I managed to blank the screen by opening black image by pqiv `pqiv -f -i blank.png&`